# Why does Tkinter not detect my true screen resolution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, screen-resolution

I'm using this code to detect and print the resolution of my screen:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

print(root.winfo_screenwidth())
print(root.winfo_screenheight())

root.mainloop()
```

However, it's printing 1440x900 instead of 2560x1600. I am on a 2017 MacBook Pro, no external displays connected, no resolution scaling active. Someone suggested using ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1) but I cannot find a MacOS equivalent.

Comment: I'll wager real money that you DO have resolution scaling turned on.  1440x900 is one of the available scalings for that display.

Comment: I don't - I made sure to check. I'm using all default settings for my display

Comment: "Default for display" on the Retina displays usually means scaled.  EXACTLY which resolution setting are you using on the Displays control panel?  Are you using "Default" or "More space"?

Comment: More space. I tried moving along that slider but it still doesn't give me the true resolution

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using the Pillow library:

```
pip install Pillow
```

```
from PIL import ImageGrab

img = ImageGrab.grab()
print(img.size)
```

I had the same problem and this seemed to work perfectly on macOS.